# Question about using residue number system for repeated multiplications

Tags: prime-numbers

I understand that when you are using RNS you need a co-prime moduli-set e.g. ${\{m_1, m_2, m_3\}}$, and the dynamic range is the product of each modulus in that set $M = m_1.m_2.m_3$. Also it's advantageous to select modulus values that are generalized mersenne numbers, so that operations in RNS are easier. And when you convert back out to an integer X you use the Chinese Remainder Theorem, something like this $ |X|_M=|\sum_{i=1}^n |r_iM_i^{-1}|_{m_i}M_i|_M$
(http://www.ccs.asia.edu.tw/ezfiles/2/1002/img/370/1203-3.pdf)

But the M / dynamic range would not necessarily be the prime you want to reduce by (for example the prime field in ECC), but all the papers I read don't really explain this, so not sure if it's something simple I'm missing or not?

For example say I have ${m_i}={2,3,5}$, this makes my $M=2.3.5=30$. So I start with value $X=7 = (1,1,2)$, do two squaring $(1,1,2)^2 = (1,1,4)^2 = (1,1,1)$, then convert out and I get $X=1$ (which is correct for $(7^2)^2$), but what if I wanted to do repeated squaring modulo a prime (e.g 23), is that possible?

Comment: A good reference book: [Residue Number Systems: Theory and Implementation](https://www.amazon.com/Residue-Number-Systems-Implementation-Engineering/dp/1860948669)

Comment: My limited understanding is that it is customary to convert from RNS to integer before results exceed $M$, then either A) compute the remainder and convert it back to RNS; B) compute the quotient, and perform the modular reduction in RNS. If there are other ways, I want to know!

Comment: @fgrieu In my archaic knowledge, for some residue systems, there is also division. However, one has to look for references.

Comment: @fgrieu As far as I understand, as long as you do the reduction mod for each $m_i$ (which isn't hard as we use generalized mersenne numbers), your result will stay within $M$ - but if you actually want it to be mod p (which you would for any ECC or RSA application) then you do have to do some extra work, like what they do here (sum of residues reduction) https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333468951_Improved_Sum_of_Residues_Modular_Multiplication_Algorithm , I was hoping there was a way around this but unless someone corrects me I don't think there is?

Comment: Definitely, when we want computation modulo $p$ and that $p$ is coprime with $M$, we can not allow intermediary results to outgrow $M$ _and_ ignore that issue. Some kind of extra work is required to prevent outgrowing $M$, or/and compensate for that. The only two methods that I'm familiar with are outlined in my previous comment. There are others.